# strtok (i suppose) bug I can't understand

Tags: c, strtok

EDIT: Minimal compiling code replicating the behaviour.

This code reads a crappy dictionary file, in order to try to extract some interesting info out of it. Each line translates to a struct entry. A word is always extracted, hence newentry() doesn't check for the validity of its word argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct entry {
char *word;
char *cat;
char *gen;
} entry;

entry *newentry(char *word, char *cat, char *gen) {
entry *w = malloc(sizeof(entry));
w->word = malloc(sizeof(strlen(word)) + 1);
strcpy(w->word, word);
if (cat) {
    w->cat = malloc(sizeof(strlen(cat)) + 1);
    strcpy(w->cat, cat);
}
else {
    w->cat = "";
}
if (gen) {
    w->gen = malloc(sizeof(strlen(gen)) + 1);
    strcpy(w->gen, gen);
}
else {
    w->gen = "";
}
return w;
}


int main() {
FILE *original = fopen("French.txt", "r");
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, original)) != -1) {
    char *word = strtok(strdup(line), "\t");
    char *tmp = strtok(NULL, "[\n");
    char *cat = strtok(NULL, "]\n");
    newentry(word, cat, tmp);           //bugs here
}
return 0;
}
```

This code fails on its line (code) line, and I have absolutely no knowledge why. If I were to replace tmp by word, cat, or a constant, it works every single time.
If I were to change the order of newentry()'s arguments, it fails every single time, so long as tmp is an argument.
I tried to debug by breaking at the while. The file that is being parsed is about 4 thousand lines, so I imagined some line (it is a very crappy file) was corrupted somehow, and I tried continue 1000, and got an exception. So I restarted and tried other values of continue - but by doing continue 100 11 times, I was able to exceed the former 1000.

My conclusion is that tmp is corrupted somehow by the following strtok. Therefore I tried
char *tmp = strdup(strtok(NULL, "[\n")); and it didn't work better.

Replacing the newentry() failing line by printf("%s %s %s", word, tmp, cat); works 100% of the times, though I can't check the 4000 values by eye.

I have really no idea how to get out of this mess, and would appreciate any pointers.

EDIT: a few lines from the data file:

```
courthouse  palais de justice[Noun]
courtier    courtisan[Noun]
courtliness e/le/gance[Adjective]
courtly e/le/gant[Adjective]
courtmartial    conseil de guerre[Noun]
courtroom   salle d'audience[Noun]
```

Thanks.

Whole input file, in case someone is really curious : http://pastebin.com/VPp8WpuK

Comment: While it might not be issue now, you should check if `malloc`s fail (return `NULL`).

Comment: You're allocating memory in `newentry` , but at no point are you freeing that memory

Comment: Please show an example line of the file.

Comment: It would be helpful if this code segment build. And if you put a comment in code telling where exactly the problem is presenting itself.  ***[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)***  (member `list` in struct is not defined anywhere)

Comment: My current intuition is that the input file has some buggy data, what kind of data could corrupt this simple strtok sequence? cat is OFTEN null, when there is no [Noun] segment at the end, and it never bugs on cat, so I don't see why it should bug on tmp, whether NULL or not.

Comment: `getline()` I believe is c++ only?

Comment: @ryyker: he's using GNU `getline()`: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html

Comment: Since your problem is answered, some other comments: you don't need to use `strdup()` in your call to `strtok()`, but you might consider using it in your `newentry()` function instead of the various `strlen()`, `malloc()`, and `strcat()` calls.  That's what `strdup()` does, you obviously know about and can use it, and it would have prevented this mistake from occurring in the first place.

Comment: My problem is sadly not answered :D Thanks all the same for the useful comments

Comment: on the other hand, these comments apparently solved the problem

Comment: How do I indicate your comment solved the difficulty?

Comment: Unrelated: `else { w->cat = "";}`  **don't** do this, it will cause some of the struct elements to point to malloc()d objects and others to string literals. This will show up once you try to destroy/free() the objects. BTW: strdup() is your friend.

Comment: +1 for _EDIT: Minimal compiling code replicating the behaviour._

Comment: I looked at the _whole input file_ you posted.  Not all of the lines will process correctly with the approach you are currently using.  Some lines have only two fields, others have three or even four.  Put strtok in a loop and test for NULL, Change the three `char *` members of `struct entry` to a single variable, array of strings, then as you loop through strtok, you can populate only the number of fields needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parsing strings you are choosing for strtok may need to be adjusted.  With the example input file. I am getting a null on the second line of strtok because the entire line is read on the first call to strtok (i.e. there is no "\t" in the line

```
char *word = strtok(StrDup(line), "\t");//reads entire line of input
char *tmp = strtok(NULL, "[\n");//NULL is returned here
char *cat = strtok(NULL, "]\n");
```

Therefore, you are passing a null into your function `newentry(,,)`

***Would it work*** to change parsing string to:

```
char *word = strtok(StrDup(line), "\t ");//added space
```

***Also*** the following lines

```
w->word = malloc(sizeof(strlen(word)) + 1);  
w->cat = malloc(sizeof(strlen(cat)) + 1);
w->gen = malloc(sizeof(strlen(gen)) + 1);
```

***should be***:

```
w->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
w->cat = malloc(strlen(cat) + 1);
w->gen = malloc(strlen(gen) + 1);
```

***One other thing***, you need to free the memory allocated in `newentry()`, which will be a problem if you need to return the struct w.  Would suggest allocating it all in `main()`, passing the struct as a pointer, then freeing it all when it comes back.

***This is how to do that...***
Create an array of `struct entry`:

```
typedef struct {
    char *word;
    char *cat;
    char *gen;
} ENTRY;  
ENTRY entry[linesInFile], *pEntry;
```

***Then*** in `main()` initialize it:

```
int main(void)
{
    pEntry = &entry[0];
    //allocate memory 
    //call redefined newentry() function
    //use results of newentry() function
    //free memory
}
```

***Now, because pEntry is a pointer*** to the entire array of `entry` it can be easily passed as an argument after calling malloc for the char * members of entry. (don't forget `free()` when it returns)

Here are the edits I had to do to make it run (does not include the re-write to get free() calls in)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct entry {
    char *word;
    char *cat;
    char *gen;
} entry;

entry *newentry(char *word, char *cat, char *gen) 
{
    entry *w = malloc(sizeof(entry));
    w->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(w->word, word);
    if (cat) 
    {
        w->cat = malloc(strlen(cat) + 1);
        strcpy(w->cat, cat);
    }
    else 
    {
        w->cat = "";
    }
    if (gen) 
    {
        w->gen = malloc(strlen(gen) + 1);
        strcpy(w->gen, gen);
    }
    else 
    {
        w->gen = "";
    }
    return w;

}


int main() 
{
    FILE *original = fopen("French.txt", "r");
    char line[260];
    int len = 260;
    //ssize_t read;
    while ( fgets(line, len, original))            
    {
        //char *word = strtok(StrDup(line), "\t ");//I dont have strdup, had to use this
        char *word = strtok(strdup(line), "\t ");
        char *tmp = strtok(NULL, "[\n");
        char *cat = strtok(NULL, "]\n");

        if((!word)||(!tmp)||(!cat)) return 0;
        word[strlen(word)]=0;
        tmp[strlen(tmp)]=0;
        cat[strlen(cat)]=0;

        newentry(word, cat, tmp);           //bugs here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the input files are sadly erroneous. There's a tab in the original file, but both SO and PB converted them to spaces. My apologies for the loss of time.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
entry *w = malloc(sizeof(entry *));
```

You want:

```
entry *w = malloc( sizeof *w );
```

or:

```
entry *w = malloc( sizeof( entry ))
```

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong please? Both expressions don't change the bugging.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(entry *)` allocates memory the size of a pointer to entry, while `malloc( sizeof *w )` allocates memory the size of what w points to.

Comment: @pouzzler `sizeof(entry *)` returns only size of the pointer, not entire struct. So you malloc too little memory.

Comment: Thank you, that's useful to know. I wish that was what causes it to bug, but that's definitely useful. Thanks again. While we're there, malloc(strlen+1) is the correct way to allocate for a string copy, yes?

Comment: @pouzzler: `malloc(sizeof(strlen(word)) + 1);` is wrong, `malloc(strlen(word) + 1);` is correct.  Even better is using `strdup()` to avoid all the manual manipulations altogether.

Comment: Ah here is the correct answer which I missed when looking at your above comment. How do I indicate your comment solved it? By checking answer 2?

Comment: So you would all recommend this idiom? w->cat = strdup(cat ? cat : "");

Comment: You certainly cannot `free` if w->cat points to a string literal, so that idiom is reasonable.